# uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread

Tags: python

I have this code (Python).

```
class CamThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, previewname, camid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewname = previewname
        self.camid = camid

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewname)
        previewcam(self.previewname, self.camid)

# Function to preview the camera.
def previewcam(previewname, camid):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewname)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camid)
    if cam.isOpened():
        rval, frame = cam.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(previewname, frame)
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27:  # Press ESC to exit/close each window.
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewname)
```

I am getting this error:

```
    Python[58828:4239666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8089e6773 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff808746bc3 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff808a0f056 -[NSException raise] + 9
        3   AppKit                              0x00007ff80b3cb0a4 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 321
        4   AppKit                              0x00007ff80b3b7054 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1288
        5   AppKit                              0x00007ff80b3b6b46 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
        6   AppKit                              0x00007ff80b697aa7 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:screen:] + 50
        7   cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x000000010d828795 cvNamedWindow + 677
        8   cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x000000010d825555 _ZN2cv11namedWindowERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi + 53
        9   cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so            0x000000010c802d5b _ZL23pyopencv_cv_namedWindowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 235
        10  Python3                             0x0000000105998c83 cfunction_call_varargs + 115
        11  Python3                             0x0000000105998709 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 377
        12  Python3                             0x0000000105a7d67c call_function + 636
        13  Python3                             0x0000000105a7a239 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28121
        14  Python3                             0x000000010599903b function_code_fastcall + 171
        15  Python3                             0x0000000105a7d54f call_function + 335
        16  Python3                             0x0000000105a7a2da _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28282
        17  Python3                             0x000000010599903b function_code_fastcall + 171
        18  Python3                             0x0000000105a7d54f call_function + 335
        19  Python3                             0x0000000105a7a215 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28085
        20  Python3                             0x000000010599903b function_code_fastcall + 171
        21  Python3                             0x0000000105a7d54f call_function + 335
        22  Python3                             0x0000000105a7a215 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 28085
        23  Python3                             0x000000010599903b function_code_fastcall + 171
        24  Python3                             0x000000010599ba33 method_vectorcall + 323
        25  Python3                             0x0000000105998a24 PyVectorcall_Call + 100
        26  Python3                             0x0000000105b1fecb t_bootstrap + 75
        27  Python3                             0x0000000105ad06d9 pythread_wrapper 
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort
```

I get it right away when starting my python file. I don't even know where to start to solve an error like this, I've never seen it before. I've read it may be an apple thing, but no clue to be honest. I am have these packages `import cv2 and import threading` as well. Anyone had this problem?